# file_get_contents displays extra characters

Tags: php, utf-8, character, file-get-contents

The script should display the content of the files, but if a lot of characters (more than 8000) at the beginning and at the end added unexpected characters (characters may change for different files).

```
b15f
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="ru" lang="ru">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
...
</body>
</html>
0
```

where are the **b15f** and **0**?

Script:

```
<?php
header("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");
header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8");
$content = file_get_contents( "index.html" );
echo($content);
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are seeing chunk lengths.

You are probably using [chunked encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chunked_transfer_encoding) and saving the results raw.  HTTP has different ways of transferring message bodies.  The most common is with a Content-Length, but you can only do this if you know the length at the time you start sending the content.  One convenient aspect of this approach is that the raw message body requires no decoding; you just read Content-Length bytes, and that's your result.

If a page is dynamic, sometimes you want to start writing bytes to the client before you know the full length.  This is when you use chunked encoding.  Each chunk is preceded by a chunk length in hex format.  After the final chunk is a 0, to indicate an empty chunk and the end of the transfer.

The server has an 8k buffer limit (I think this is default for PHP, for example), which means after the body gets larger than 8k, it is sent in chunks.  So after the file is larger than 8k, you get chunk sizes interspersed in your data.

**Solution:**

```
ob_start();
echo($content);
header('Content-Length: '.ob_get_length());
ob_end_flush();
```

Comment: Thanks, seems to be true.
How can I fix it? Which option in the server settings fix?

Comment: I'm not sure if you can change it without recompiling PHP.  Also, it might be Apache or Nginx doing it.  You may be able to explicitly use output buffering (ob_start() before the content, then echo ob_get_clean() after the content), but I'm not sure.  If not, you can try ALSO sending an explicit Content-Length header right before you echo the buffered content, which should force the issue.